# How to implement infinite scroll using react query for NewsApi

Tags: javascript, react-query

I want to implement infinite scroll using the useInfiniteQuery hook. The response that the api gives is-

```js
{
"status": "ok",
// Total articles present in the server
"totalResults": 36,
// Array of articles per requwst
-"articles": []
-}
```

My  function to fetch the data is-

```js
// Here pageSize represents the no of articles in one page 
// Page represents on which page we are currently on

async function fetchPage({pageParam = 1}){
  const response = await fetch(
        `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&pageSize=10&page=${pageParam}&apiKey=${API_KEY}`
     );
     
  return response.json()
}
```

When I use the useInfiniteQuery hook how should I define the getNextPageParam ?
According to my understanding getNextPageParam is used to update the pageParam of the fetch function that is set  to 1 by default.
My code is-

```js
const {
            isLoading,
            data,
            fetchNextPage,
        } = useInfiniteQuery(["news"], fetchPage, {
            getNextPageParam: (lastPage) => {
      // lastpage is the last response object.It has articles, totalResults and status
      // What should be the condition when articles.length == 10
                lastPage.articles.length < 10 ? undefined : 
            },
        });

if (isLoading){return (<p>Loading ...</p>)}
    
    const news = data.articles
    console.log(data.totalResults)
    console.log(news)
    return (
        <>
            {news.map((n) => (
                <div key={n.title} className="block">
                    <div><img src={n.urlToImage}></img></div>
                    <h2>{n.title}</h2>
                    <div>{n.description}</div>
                    <a href={ n.url}> Read More</a>
                </div>
            ))}
            <button
                onClick={() => {
                    fetchNextPage()
                }}
            >
                More data
            </button>
        </>
    );
}


 
 
  

export default App
```